# Radius of Convergence of Taylor Series

Tags: taylor-expansion

Starting with $f(x) = sin x$ centered at $a = \frac{\pi}{6}$, I got the following Taylor Series expansion: 
$$\sin x = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \Big(x - \frac{\pi}{6}\Big) - \frac{1}{4} \Big(x - \frac{\pi}{6}\Big)^2 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{12} \Big(x - \frac{\pi}{6}\Big)^3 + \ldots$$

My goal here is to write the power-series representation and then use the ratio test to find the radius of convergence. It seems that each term has a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{n!}$ starting at $n = 0$, and $\Big(x - \frac{\pi}{6}\Big)^n$ starting at $n = 0$. From here, I haven't been able to figure out how to deal with the alternating signs for every third term or the alternating $\sqrt{3}$ (since we swap back and forth from $\sin$ to $\cos$ if we continuously take derivatives.)

I also tried writing $\sin x$ in the general form of a power series, $\frac{1}{1-r}$ (using $r$ in place of $x$, though it's usually writing with $x$), but then I ran into the issue of not knowing what to do with $\sin x$.

I'd appreciate any help anyone could offer.

Comment: Are you looking for an explicit expansion of $\sin x$ near $x=\frac \pi6$ or are you chiefly interested to prove that the sought expansion has an infinite radius of convergence?

Comment: I actually didn't know what the radius of convergence was and was trying to find this. I computed the Taylor expansion of this, as above, as the first step of the problem, but this didn't seem to lend itself to any clear conclusions on convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The series will be $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(x-\pi/6)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(x-\pi/6)^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$

This can be obtained by the Maclaurin series of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. If we let $t=x-\pi/6$, then $\sin x=\sin (t+\pi/6)=\frac{1}{2}\sin t+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\cos t$. Since the Maclaurin series of $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ are known we can find it and then put $t=x-\pi/6$. It is also known that the radius of convergence of both series are infinity.